# Ready-to-use time and/or datetime selection widgets for GTK3?

Tags: python, application-development, gtk3

I've checked `hamster-applet`, `gnome-control-center datetime` and `gnome-schedule`. They all define a different datetime selection composed from basic widgets. I'm surprised it wasn't made available as a single widget. Did I miss it somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the calendar you can use `Gtk.Calendar` which is part of GTK itself (and available to embed in your app in Glade. I am not aware of a slider for selecting the time, but you could add this easily with some `Gtk.SpinButton` widgets.

Comment: Well, I've done exactly this (`lp:~xintx-ua/wakeonplan/wakeonplan`). But having one unified widget would be nice :)